# Is there an online PGN editor for Blank Chess?

Tags: chess-variants, notation

[Blank Chess](http://www.blankchess.com/) is a variant where the board starts empty and the first two moves are placing the Kings on your side of the board. You can then either place a piece or move a piece in subsequent turns.

I recorded a game I played with my son in the same notation one would use for [CrazyHouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazyhouse), and would like to record it in a PGN (or [BPGN](http://bughousedb.com/Lieven_BPGN_Standard.txt)) format to show it to friends.

Does anyone know where I can find such an editor online, or failing that, one that I can download to my Mac?

Comment: Blank chess? Never heard of it before. Sounds cool.

Comment: It appears to be one of the most original tactically open variants I've seen. I've not played enough to know how it will play out strategically yet.

Comment: Oh so kinda like Bughouse where you notate it ex: p@e7 right?

Comment: Correct. @theppright The notation for dropping a piece on the board is p@e7 for a Pawn dropped on e7. In Blank Chess you can drop your pieces on your own side of the board.

Comment: Can i play Blank chess online anywhere?? seems very interesting.

Comment: @PavanNadig Not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

[Caissa's PGN Editor](http://www.caissa.com/chess-tools/pgn-editor.php) claims to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about the [lichess.com editor](https://en.lichess.org/editor)? [Here is a link](https://en.lichess.org/editor/8/8/8/8/8/8/8/8_w_-_-) to a board exactly as you describe I believe. Just click and drag any piece to the board. You can also share a URL at every state of the game which is pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.apronus.com/chess/wbeditor.php
The "position setup" part of the dual interface allows setting up anything on the board without regard for legal moves. Each change to the board is recorded in memory and then can be exported to an animated GIF file. You can delete some of the positions from the animation sequence to create an exact scenario to fit your needs, just check the ckeckbox "animation sequence".

[image: demo animation]

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

http://www.apronus.com/chess/wbeditor.php?w=8&h=8

You can create your own position, load/export PGN/FEN formats.

Comment: You would have to diagram each and every position to get a fen. It cant just drop pieces in and show it.

Comment: He's right, this is just as unsavory as creating the PNG by hand.

Comment: That page has been updated and is now able to show the scenario of any chess variant that uses the standard pieces.